# Why am i getting index of the range error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

```
def oburparaust(liste, money):
moneycontrol = 0.0
coin=0
control = 0
while True:
    if liste[control] > money:
        control+=1
    else:
        moneycontrol+=liste[control]
        coin+=1
        if moneycontrol==money:
            break
        elif moneycontrol > money:
            moneycontrol-=liste[control]
            coin-=1
            print(moneycontrol)
            if control>len(liste)-1:
                print(moneycontrol)
                control=len(liste)-1
            else:
                control+=1
    #print(coin)
oburparaust([1.0, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01], 5.38)
```

I want to calculate how much coin was used for the money of 5.38. but i get index of the range error i couldn't find why where am i going over the list?

Error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "xxxx", line 26, in 
     oburparaust([1.0, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01], 5.38)
     File "xxxx", line 6, in oburparaust
     if liste[kontrol] > a:
     IndexError: list index out of range
     moneycontrol:  1.0    Coin:  1
     moneycontrol:  2.0    Coin:  2
     moneycontrol:  3.0    Coin:  3
     moneycontrol:  4.0    Coin:  4
     moneycontrol:  5.0    Coin:  5
     moneycontrol:  5.0    Coin:  5
     moneycontrol:  5.0    Coin:  5
     moneycontrol:  5.25    Coin:  6
     moneycontrol:  5.25    Coin:  6
     moneycontrol:  5.35    Coin:  7
     moneycontrol:  5.35    Coin:  7
     moneycontrol:  5.35    Coin:  7
     moneycontrol:  5.359999999999999    Coin:  8
     moneycontrol:  5.369999999999999    Coin:  9
     moneycontrol:  5.379999999999999    Coin:  10
     moneycontrol:  5.379999999999999    Coin:  10
```

Comment: In line 6 `if liste[control] > money:` its looping through and trying to get item with key 6, which is not present in the array.

Comment: change this `while True:` to this `while True and control < len(liste):`

Comment: @komatiraju032 tip: `True and watever` equals to just `watever`

Comment: thanks komatiraju032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have list "liste" with 6 items, what means that your index starts with 0 and ends with 5, in the point when your variable control will have value 6, index will be out of the range. you will need to control that variable "control" if it is less than length of your list "liste". Something like:

```
def oburparaust(liste, money):
    moneycontrol = 0.0
    coin=0
    control = 0
    while control < len(liste):
           . . .
```

Comment: I guess it would be fair to let @komtatiraju032 to post this answer, as he was first in the comments

Comment: @Marat what I can notice it was at the same time, while I was writing an answer I couldnt notice that there is a new comment , or I could ?

Comment: While it is still your choice what to do, I can tell you that his comment (and even OP's response to the comment) appeared first and both his comment and your answer share the same logic mistake (see my comment). It just doesn't look good. Also, imo using `for` loop would be a lot better here

Comment: also, when you write an answer you can see there are new comments, but you need to click on the placeholder to see their content (same as with post edits). I guess now when the answer is accepted it doesn't matter anyway.